# React Native : Network request failed

Tags: android, react-native

I got my local server running on 127.0.0.1:8080 using wamp server.
I Try to post it using postman and data is able to post and save to db.
[image]

But when i try to post it in react native, it shows Network request failed as below
[image]

This is my code

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/register', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    })
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
      console.log(responseData.body)
  })
  .done();
```

If i key in the address 127.0.0.1:8080 in my pc browser it's able to direct me to my localhost page.

But in my emulator i noticed it's using LTE and when i access 127.0.0.1:8080 with the browser, it's not able to connect. By right the emulator is connect to the same network as my pc, it should be able to access, right ?

Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Have you tried fetching using https vs http?

Comment: Hi Nader Dabit,
I've tried both, it's the same

Comment: Your PC and emulator are two different machines, even though the emulator is virtual. For the emulator, 127.0.0.1 is itself, not the PC. You will have to use the PC's actual address.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `10.0.2.2` or go to command prompt and hit `ipconfig` then copy the ip address. It will be like `192.168.5.10`